# Install npm packages in Python virtualenv

Tags: python, npm, installation, pip

There are some npm packages which I would like to install in a Python virtualenv. For example:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui

Up to now I only found the complicated way to get these installable in a virtualenv: Create a python package for them.

Is there no simpler way to get npm packages installed in a Python virtualenv?

Answer (score 18):

You can install NPM packages on your python virtuaenv using nodeenv.

```
source ./bin/activate
pip install nodeenv
nodeenv -p
```

To test if works:

```
npm install -g npm
npm -v
```

Sources:

https://pypi.org/project/nodeenv/

https://calvinx.com/2013/07/11/python-virtualenv-with-node-environment-via-nodeenv/

Comment: The only problem I see is that you will need to worry about two lock files, and two package files, is there a way to do a pipenv install that runs post install the npm install to get the packages for node?

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you for it.

Answer (score 11):

NPM and pip have nothing to do with each other, so you won't be able to install NPM packages inside a virtualenv.

However: [NPM installs packages in `./node_modules`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders).

So if you created a virtualenv and installed npm modules inside it

```
virtualenv myproj
cd myproj
source bin/activate
npm install pdfjs-dist jquery-ui
```

you will end up with the node packages in `myproj/node_modules`, which is as close as it gets to "installing NPM inside virtualenv".

Comment: Exactly this. If your project uses both Javascript and Python, then you need a `virtualenv` environment for python packages and `node_modules` for node modules.

Answer (score 4):

As @Josir suggests, I have used `nodeenv` in the past but I had an issue when I wanted to have the node modules inside the `venv` folder of the project as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139016/moving-node-modules-location-under-a-python-venv).

In short putting a `package.json` in `venv` results in not being able to use `npx ...` unless it is run from the `venv` folder whereas putting `package.json` in `venv/lib` and running `npm install` from there results in being able to use `npx ...` from any folder in the project.

This is due to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable being set to `<myproject>/venv/lib/node_modules`.

I created a script to automate this which in substance does:

```
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install requirements.txt
cp package.json venv/lib
cd venv/lib
nodeenv -p
npm install --no-optional
```