# Moving node_modules location under a Python venv

Tags: python, node.js, virtual-environment

I have a Python venv to develop a Django application and I use `babel` to transpile my javascript.

Currently, I install `node.js` with `nodeenv -p` whilst working under my Python venv.

Everything works fine if I have the `node_modules` and `package.json` folder at the root of my project, but it is messing up the project folder structure.

I would rather have `node_modules` under `venv`:

```
project_folder
   |
   |- venv
         |- node_modules
         package.json
```

or even:

```
project_folder
   |
   |- venv
         |- node
               |- node_modules
               package.json
```

If I put my `package.json` in `venv` and execute `npm install` from there, `npx babel` only works if I am in `venv`, not a the root of the project.

Running `npx babel` from the project's root directory gives me:

```
npx: installed 1 in 0.655s
You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in Babel 6.
Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package to the `babel-cli` package.

    npm uninstall -g babel
    npm install --save-dev babel-cli

See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ for setup instructions.
```

How can I have `node_modules` under the `venv` folder and be able to use `npx babel` from anywhere in the project folder?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974436/change-node-modules-location) is related but I can't see how to adapt the answer to `nodeenv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured out that `NODE_PATH` is set to `<myproject>/venv/lib/node_modules`.

If I put my `package.json` file in `venv/lib/` then run `npm install` from this directory, I can use `npx babel` from any folder in the project.